# Pattern for Parallel and Thread Safe Serial

Tags: .net, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

Is there a pattern to combine parallel with a thread safe calculation on the parallel?

Need to calculate a result in which the first step would benefit from parallel and the second is a serial process on the results of the parallel.

One option is to run the parallel and save the output to a collection and then serially process the collection and I have that working.  The problem there is memory management as the collection can be very large.

Below is the serial version.  Basially I want to parallel the TableQueryGetRowKeys and use that result in a thread safe manner.  Tried to just Parallel the for and put a lock around the final results but rowKeys could be off.  Tried aggregate but I could not figure out how to pass a collection to the aggregate let alone perform thread safe Intersect in the aggregate.

```
IEnumerable<string> finalResults = null;
if (partitionKey.Length == 0) return finalResults;
object lockObject = new object();
finalResults = TableQueryGetRowKeys(partitionKey[0], 0);
HashSet<string> rowKeys;
for(int i = 1; i < partitionKey.Length; i++)
{
    // IO operation to Azure Table Storage against the PartitionKey
    // so very amenable to parallel
    rowKeys = TableQueryGetRowKeys(partitionKey[i]);
    // a memory and CPU operation 
    // this should be much faster than TableQueryGetRowKeys
    // going parallel and wrapping this in a lock did not properly synch rowKeys
    finalResults = finalResults.Intersect(rowKeys); 
}
return finalResults;
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail?  As in, how are you processing your data?

Comment: In this code TableQueryGetRowKeys is just a dummy routine.  In real life it will be a query to Azure Table Storage on the PartitionKey and return the RowKeys.  The Interset is to get the set of RowKeys common the the set of PartitionKeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `TableQueryGetRowKeys` is thread safe:

```
var final = partitionKey.AsParallel()
                        // By returning AsParallel we can get parallel intersect
                        .Select(k => TableQueryGetRowKeys(k).AsParallel())
                        .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y));

// Using fake-ish data I see about a 30% speed-up on a 4-core machine:
// static HashSet<string> TableQueryGetRowKeys(string prefix)
// {
//     // Simulate 1s of IO round-trip
//     if (useSleep) Thread.Sleep(1000);
//
//     return new HashSet<string>(
//         Enumerable.Range(0, 500)
//                   .Select(_ => random.Value.Next(0, 500).ToString()));
// }
```

In stepwise fashion this algorithm works like so:

1. `partitionKey.AsParallel()` turns the regular `IEnumerable<string>` into a `ParallelQuery<string>` which allows parallel processing of the sequence.
2. Next, `ParallelEnumerable.Select` is used to call `TableQueryGetRowKeys` in parallel.
3. The result of each call to `TableQueryGetRowKeys` is then wrapped in a `ParallelQuery<T>` using `AsParallel()`.
4. `ParallelEnumerable.Intersect` is used as an aggregation function over each "parallel-enabled" enumeration returned by `TableQueryGetRowKeys`.

---

In effect, this could be used *in serial* to replace your previous code by removing the `AsParallel` calls, like so:

```
var serialEquivalent = partitionKey.Select(k => TableQueryGetRowKeys(k))
                                   .Aggregate((x,y) => x.Intersect(y));
```

You can "convince" yourself that this is equivalent to your method when you look at the meat and potatoes of your implementation:

```
IEnumerable<string> results = SomeMethod(0);
for (int ii = 1; ii < count; ++ii)
{
    results = results.Intersect(SomeMethod(ii));
}
```

Rewriting the above using `+` instead of `Intersect`:

```
int results = SomeMethod(0);
for (int ii = 1; ii < count; ++ii)
{
    results = results + SomeMethod(ii);
}
```

Now it becomes clear that `Intersect` could be used in place of other more "common" aggregation functions (e.g. mathematical operators).

Comment: Let me do some testing.  It is so slick I don't even understand it - yet.  On the .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y)) is x the result of the .Select and y is is a variable of the aggregate?

Comment: I've used the overload where the [source type is also the accumulator type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383981). Given that the `Select` returns "rows" which are enumerations themselves, the accumulator will be an enumeration. If you think of `Intersect` like `Sum` (or `+`), this starts to make more sense.

Comment: Thanks, don't fully understand it yet.  But I ran enough tests that I am comfortable with the answer.  I still don't get x,y.  How does a parallel-enabled enumeration translate to two variables?

Comment: Ah: `(ParallelQuery<string> accumulator, ParallelQuery<string> element) => ...`, and we use [`ParallelEnumerable.Intersect` which takes two `ParallelQuery<T>`'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642139). If you look at this [Enumerable.Aggregate overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) and compare it to the ParallelEnumerable version I'm using you'll see how they're "equivalent". This is where the power of the parallel LINQ extensions comes into play!